# Find replace string before and after

Tags: sed

I have been trying to do a sed replace.  For some reason, I just can't my head around sed and regular expressions (this is my second sed question)

Basically I want to find text and replace then find the next occurrence of some text and replace that

So far I have this

```
echo "This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed \$\{hcvar-BookName\} and this would remain" | sed 's/$\\{hcvar-/" + hcvar-/g'
```

This returns:

```
*This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed " + hcvar-BookName\} and this would remain*
```

However I want to return

```
*This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed " + hcvar-BookName + " and this would remain*
```

This would replace the } with + "

The logic would be something like:

```
Find: \$\{hcvar-
Replace with:  " + hcvar-
Then find the next occurrence of: \}
Replace with: + "
```

The second bit to replace would be right after the string that contains: hcvar-

This should work for the following string examples

- This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed
  \${hcvar-BookName} and this would remain
- This could be anywhere and
  this bit should be changed \${hcvar-somethingelse} and this would
  remain
- This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed
  \${hcvar-wouldnevercontainspaces} and this would remain

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape $ with a backslash:

`echo "This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed \$\{hcvar-BookName\} and this would remain" | sed -e 's/\$\\{hcvar-/" + hcvar-/g' -e 's/\\}/ +/'`

Output:

`This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed " + hcvar-BookName + and this would remain`

Comment: In POSIX sed `$` is literal if it's not the last character in the `pattern` part of the substitute command. In many flavors however `$` will not be literal if it's the last logical character, i.e: `s/\(a\|$\)/b/` will replace `a` or the null byte after the pattern space with `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is actually:

```
... changed ${hcvar-BookName} and ...
```

Then the following will work:

```
$ sed 's/${\([^}]*\)}/" + \1 + "/' file.txt
This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed " + hcvar-BookName + " and this would remain
```

Note use single quotes to preserve what would otherwise be special characters for the shell:

```
$ echo '...changed ${hcvar-BookName} and ...' | sed '...'
```

If the input is does actually use `\{` i.e: `... $\{hello\} ...`, then this might work:

```
$ sed 's/$\\{\([^}]*\)\\}/" + \1 + "/' file.txt
This could be anywhere and this bit should be changed " + hcvar-BookName + " and this would remain
```

Breakdown:

```
s/            /          / # Replace ... with ...
  ${         }             # Literal ${ and literal }
    \(     \)              # \( and \) is a capturing group
      [^}]*                # Match everything but } zero or more times
               " + \1 + "  # \1 will be expanded to the captured result
                           # from \(, \). The rest is literal
```

Add the `g`lobal if you need multiply substitutions on each line:

```
s/pattern/replacement/g
#                     ^ Global flag
```